# Bootstrap button with icon font duplicate JavaScript event issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following button:

```
<a href="/operation" class="btn btn-xlg btn-marine center-block" title="" data-original-title="Manage active jobs' Operations" aria-describedby="tooltip598388">
  <i class="fox-operation"></i>Operations
</a>
```

And this is its CSS roles:

```
.btn-xlg {
    padding: 20px 16px;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1.3333333;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-shadow: 1px 0 2px #000;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.btn.btn-xlg i {
    float: left;
    border-right: solid 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 72px;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 0;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: -26px;
}
.btn-marine {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0AA;
    border-color: #0AA;
}
.center-block {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.fox-operation:before {
    content: '\e801';
}
[class^="fox-"]:before, [class*=" fox-"]:before {
    font-family: "fox";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    speak: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    width: 1em;
    margin-right: .2em;
    text-align: center;
    /* opacity: .8; */
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin-left: .2em;
    font-size: 120%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.3);
}
```

I'm using [Animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) to maintain animation effects while hover the button like the following:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
          $(".btn-xlg").hover(function(){

              $(this).addClass('animated bounce').one(animationEnd, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('animated bounce');

        });
          })
      })
      </script>
```

The problem is that hover event seems to be invoked again after moving on the button from the text to the icon font. I have tried to use `mouseover` instead of `hover` also I tried the selector `a.btn.btn-xlg:not('i')` but the same result. I don't know why JavaScript re invokes the event while I'm on the same element `a`?

Checkout this [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/vivohih/edit?output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `mouseenter` event instead of `mouseover`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
          
    $(".btn-xlg").on("mouseenter", function(){
        $(this).addClass('animated bounce').one(animationEnd, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('animated bounce');  
        });
    });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/curveball/b5zvd53g/)

> The mouseenter event is fired when a pointing device (usually a mouse) is moved over the element that has the listener attached.
>
> Similar to mouseover, it differs in that it doesn't bubble and that **it isn't sent when the pointer is moved from one of its descendants' physical space to its own physical space.**

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter)

Comment: Thank you very much. It is perfect and well explained solution.